# Phaserio Dynamic Sprite Creation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, meteor, phaser-framework

I am using PhaserIO in conjunction with Meteor to create a multiplayer html5 game and have run into a snag I cannot seem to figure out in a networking prototype I was making. First, the relevant code (also available as a [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Sinistralis/2a47b62214e18beaf253/raw/a8a713fdf6647b18a8784f44472661deda5356a5/game.js)):

```js
if(Meteor.isClient) {

    var game,
        mainState,
        mainStateInitialized,
        characterData;

    Template.game.game = function() {

        characterData = Character.find().fetch();

        if(!mainStateInitialized)
        {
            game = new Phaser.Game(500, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameScreen');
            createMainState()
        }     
    }
}

function createMainState()
{
    mainState = {
        sprites: null,
        playerLastFrame: characterData.length,
        playerCurrentFrame: null,
        charData: characterData,

        preload: function() {
            this.sprites = game.add.group();
            game.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;
            game.load.image('hello', 'resources/hello.png');
        },

        create: function() {
            $.each(characterData, function(index) {
                var sprite = mainState.sprites.create(this.x, this.y, 'hello');
                sprite.angle = this.angle;
            });
        },

        update: function() {
            this.charData = characterData;
            this.playersCurrentFrame = this.charData.length;

            if(this.playersLastFrame > this.playersCurrentFrame) {
                //todo: remove player that left
            }
            else if(this.playersLastFrame < this.playersCurrentFrame) {
                for(var i = playersLastFrame; i < playersCurrentFrame; i++) {
                    var thisData = this.charData[i],
                        sprite = null;
                    sprite = mainState.sprites.create(thisData.x, thisData.y, 'hello');
                    sprite.angle = thisData.angle;
                }
            }
            for(var j = 0; j < mainState.sprites.length; j++) {
                mainState.sprites.getAt(j).angle = this.charData[j].angle;
            }
            playersLastFrame = this.charData.length;
        }
    }

    game.state.add('main', mainState);
    game.state.start('main');
    mainStateInitialized = true;
}
```

The idea of this prototype is to have a sprite shown in the canvas for each account in the DB. The main features I am testing are:

1. Dynamically adding sprites/player data seamlessly (as all proper multiplayer online games should be capable of. This will eventually pave the way for  a proper join/leave system)
2. And to mess with creating efficient packets.

Right now, I am running into an issue with dynamically creating a new sprite when a player creates a new account. About 75% of the time, when a player makes a new account nothing happens. Meteor correctly pushes down the character data, which I can query, and `mainState.sprites` correctly shows the sprite data. However, nothing is rendered on the canvas.

The other 25% of the time, it works fine. In addition, if I have the code break-pointed it works 100% of the time as far as I can tell.

So, something intermittent is obviously occurring here but I can't figure out what the issue is. Is there something I am missing when adding a sprite during the update loop? Is there a better way to approach this?

I have my code on Nitrous.io, so I can run a localhost instance for you to hit if it would help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was not setting playersLastFrame = playersCurrentFrame.

I feel silly now considering this is a basic loop/compare structure. last = current at end of loop.

Sigh : (.